# Measure two max value in Excel graph

Tags: excel, graph, line, measure, spectral-density

In the context, I have a star spectral graph and there are two spectral line. The coordonate of graph are : x = Angstrom and y = relative intensity.

For example, on 6562 Angstrom there is a relative intensity of 2.12 and on 6520 Angstrom 2.19.

I would like measure the highest spots on the graph for more measurement.
I use Excel.

for example this picture (two spectral line example)

[image: Two spectral line example]
<sub>(source: [shelyak.com](https://www.shelyak.com/client/gfx/utilisateur/Image/Be_02_zetTau.png))</sub>

how could I find these two points in automatic ways?

Comment: Don't use the graph but use LARGE() on the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add a third column to your data with the following formula:

```
'Assuming your data for "Relative intensity" is in column B
=IF(B1>=LARGE($B$1:$B$100,2),B1,NA())
```

Then, add an extra series to your line plot with this column (which should have only the 2 highest values and #N/A for the rest). Hide the line, add markers and data labels for this new line on your plot. You should get something like this, which updates automatically to highlight only the 2 highest values.

[image]

---

EDIT: Added a screenshot of my graph with 1500 points. Here I changed the formula to reach the end of my data table (this will of course not be exactly the same range on your sheet. look at where your data starts and where it ends):

```
=IF(B2>=LARGE($B$2:$B$1502,2),B2,NA())
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your responses. Your answer works because you have ~12 points but i have 1300 points and on my example i have one point found ...

Comment: Adjust in my formula the part where it says `$B$1:$B$100`. Change the *100* to make it reach the end of your data table. It should work perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, feel free to accept answer if Q is closed and let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.